# How To Output Data From iPhone To Console While Testing On Real Device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, console, simulator

I work with the iPhone simulator for quiet a while now and it's all great. But now I want to do the next step and transfer my software directly to my iPhone/iPad. So I am about to buy the developer license to do so. But one question still remains: When using the sim my console output is shown in Xcode by using NSLog for example.

So for example: I want to receive the current GPS data I get, when using the MapKit. In the sim it's quite easy to log to the console some "fake data". But how do I receive a constantly updating GPS position when using my real device? How do I get the console output when it is not run in the sim? Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/wiki)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run the iphone in debug mode and keep it connected. Then u should see the feedback in the console!

Answer (score 1):

You can still attach XCode as a debugger when running your application on an iDevice. You'll be able to use the console and step through the code, just as if it was running in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a (free) app that shows all debugging output on your iPhone - check out

http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/console/id317676250?mt=8

It's sometimes quite useful - and I suppose when you want to get GPS output you won't have your Mac around when you're on the go ;-).